# Does python on Ubuntu come with any libraries?

Tags: python, python3, libraries, python-2.7

I'm asking this because it appears to me that the standard Ubuntu installation already comes packaged with the python library requests (although I could be wrong about this). Is there a list of, if any, libraries Ubuntu python comes with?

Comment: A few thoughts aside: some python libs are *part* of Ubuntu, you'd better never uninstall or overwrite these. They are installed in `/usr`. Instead, if one day you need an updated version of such lib, you can install it as the standard user. They will go in `/usr/local` or even in your home directory if you specify so. A better thing would be to work inside a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of available Python 3 modules, open a terminal then run:

```
python3 -c 'help("modules")'
```

for Python 2 run:

```
python -c 'help("modules")'
```

---

As for the ones that come preinstalled with Ubuntu, these are the ones included in the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/) and installed with `libpython-stdlib` and `libpython3-stdlib` packages in Ubuntu as shown in [the package information for Python 2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python) and [for Python 3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I believe this also displays the modules I installed manually. My question was in regards to modules that come pre-packaged with Ubuntu.

Comment: @NicolasSchapeler Updated the answer to include python modules installed by default.

Comment: Thank you for the extension of your answer. So judging from that, ubuntu does NOT come with python-requests installed as I had previously assumed, correct?

Comment: @NicolasSchapeler No, only the ones listed.