# Can't import installed package in python

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip, python-2.7

I've Installed Charm-Crypto in my ubuntu 18.04 and I can find this library files in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` path.

But when I try to import this library I'm getting this error message:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import charm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named charm
>>>
```

Anyone can help me with this problem??

The output of `which python` is:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

`sys.path` is:

```py
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/solat/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1226562/968501

Comment: If there's a package on your `path`, depend on your installation way, maybe the compiled bytecodes cause the problem. Please `cd` on the package folder and delete them (e.g. `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`). Does it help?

Comment: Thanks Raffa, I've find my problem. I used wrong version of python for importing this library.