# I have several python versions installed and I want to remove the packages installed under them

Tags: python, python3, pip, python-2.7

Using pip I am only able to uninstall for a few versions. I am fairly new to this, so please let me know if there is some way of deleting it. I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04. I had previously installed the packages with pip itself. But now pip no longer points to those versions. I tried commands like
`pip3.6 uninstall package`
`python3.6 -m pip uninstall package`

but none of that is even being recognised as a command.
I do not wish to uninstall the python installation itself, just the various packages that I installed by myself when using those various versions.

I have installed python3.6 version as I can see it under my /usr and home directory, however when I run this `python3.6 -m pip -V` or `python3.6 -m pip list` I get the following output

```
Command 'python3.6' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3.9' from deb python3.9 (3.9.0-5~20.04)
  command 'python3.8' from deb python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: It's `pip uninstall package` and `pip3 uninstall package` not `pip3.6 uninstall package` [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226559/does-python-on-ubuntu-come-with-any-libraries) is also related .

Comment: I have tried that too, but pip3 points to my python 3.8 installation

Comment: You'd be crazy uninstalling anything beginning with "P" and ending in "ython".

Comment: What does `python3.6 -m pip -V` and `python3.6 -m pip list` return? Please [edit] your question to add the output.

Comment: @Raffa, I have edited the question.

Comment: `python3.6` is not present on your system or not configured / linked correctly. You appear to have `python3.8` and `python3.9`. Given this information, I suggest you leave the installed python packages and read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321433)

Answer (score 3):

Do not - **ever** - remove a python version if you did not install it yourself. Ubuntu has tons of scripts running in python - therefore it needs a defined python environment. There are a lot of "I've removed python now I have a [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223013/i-accidentally-removed-python-from-ubuntu-graphical-interface-gone)" questions in this forum - due to a removal of the "official" python environment.

You always can install additional versions via pip and remove them. And you can set those as [default version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu)

**Edit**
Just of today python V3.8.5 is the current "offical" version of Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: As I understand it .... The OP does not want to uninstall any python version. They want to remove packages they previously manually installed **pip** and no longer need. **+1**

Comment: Yes, I do not intend to remove the python installation just some packages that I installed on my own when I was using that version of python such as TensorFlow which is eating up a lot of space.